# top 50% doesn't work on element with height set by padding-bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm not getting it, why can't I use `%` value for the `top` in `.bg h1`? There's defined height by `padding-bottom` for the element, so it sound like the formal thing to set the height. Is there any workaround of this, but without making it absolute and so it would be responsive.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.bg h1 {
  color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; //change to absolute to ensure 
  //there is height value set without text inside
  top: 50%; //50px DOES work
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kannan it's simple  - I want `top: 50%` to work without declaring height(except for `auto`) and without absolute positioning or alike

Comment: I don't understand why you do not want to use `position: absolute`.

Comment: It's complicate, @Terry. I would share the code if I could.

Comment: @swellar thanks for the running code snippet. I didn't find this option. cool

Comment: @yagepoca , If you used `padding-bottom` , `h1` can't identify its parent height with `position:relative`.

Comment: @ankitapatel nice thought, I thought that too :) but it's not the case. try to use `height: 100%` on html and body and it won't work either. Or perhaps there's something more?

Comment: @yagepoca you can never center it with uneven padding on `.bg` and without using `position:absolute;`

Comment: @ankitapatel Oh, I misread your message... Yeah. That's the point... It sounds like a formal thing, because padding-bottom does declare height for the element, just not in a formal `height` way. and it's odd

Comment: @ab29007 who told you that I want to center it? SHOW ME THE ONE! :) I just need the `top` to work with `%` value

Comment: @yagepoca , hmm now you understand my point...:)

Comment: When using % in height, the parent of the element needs to have a fixed height... If the parent also use % in this case you need to add % height all they way till html element. Basically: html, body, .bg {height:100%}. Browsers just can't understand 50% of no height

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez That's just not the case, pal. `padding-bottom` is the only thing that generates height(along with the `text`). That's the whole problem here... there's height, but not `height`... and `top` is fixed for the `height` to be set. It's ridiculous

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.bg {
  background:#333;
  //text-align:center;
  //position:relative;
  //height: auto;
  //padding-bottom: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}
.bg h1 {
  color:#eee;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  //position: absolute; //change to absolute to ensure 
                     //there is height value set without text inside
  //top:50%; //50px DOES work
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

I suggest `display: flex`;

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.bg {
  background:#333;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  //height: auto;
  //padding-bottom: 20%;
  height: 100px;
}
.bg h1 {
  color:#eee;
  //margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position: absolute; //change to absolute to ensure 
                     //there is height value set without text inside
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah, thanks. I need cross-browser and platform support. No flex here

Comment: I need it to be responsive. No fixed height, pal. But thanks for helping around

Comment: @yagepoca Must use `padding-bottom`?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this. Give height as you want in `.bg` class. In class `.bg h1` give `top:50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);` for centering text.

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.bg {
  background:#333;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  height: 100px; 
}
.bg h1 {
  color:#eee;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative; 
  top:50%; 
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline-block and a pseudo element. which eill be too thin and with matching background with `.bg` to be noticeable.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

.bg{
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  /* padding-bottom: 20%; */
  /* height:100px; */
  padding:10% 0;
}
.pseudo{
  display: inline-block;
  width:1px;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:#cccccc;
}
.bg h1{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="pseudo"></div>
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Em... what `.pseudo` element for? 0_o It doesnt contribute at all... And I need `top` to work, but thanks

Comment: it is for vertical-align property to work (wightout `position:abolute;` of `Flexbox`) so that it's other siblings don't have to go full height of the container `.bg`. Thought you wanted to center heading but I can't make the `top` work. sorry.

Comment: you don't need it there, buddy :) your `padding: 10%` is doing the magic ;-) try and see